# Convert Objective-C syntax to Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift

What will be the syntax of the following Objective-C method in Swift?

```
-(id)init
{
    Viewcontroller static *vc=nil;
    if(!vc)
    {
        vc=[super init];
        return vc;
    }
    else return vc;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a free code translation service. Please make an attempt to convert the code yourself. Update your question with what you have tried and clearly explain what issues you are having.

Answer (score -2):

Below is the syntax in Swift 3

```
override init() {
    var vc: Viewcontroller? = nil
    if vc == nil {  
        vc = super.init()
        return vc!
    }
    else {    
        return vc!
    }
}
```

Comment: sir, where is static key word?

Comment: @ManzoorHusain When you define a static var/let into a class , that information will be shared among all the instances (or values).

Comment: will it be "var" or "let" ?

Comment: Using Let you make constant object and using Var you can make mutable object